# How to reuse a method from another step definition class Appium/Cucumber/Java

Tags: java, android, cucumber, appium

Trying to reuse a method in another class, initialising the class like this:

```
public class SettingsStepDefs {
public Scenario scenario;

@Autowired
public AndroidBase androidBase;
public GenericStepDefs genericStepDefs;


@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
    genericStepDefs = new GenericStepDefs();
```

and then later using the method

```
genericStepDefs.iTapDone();
```

However i am getting a Null pointer exception on the line above.

The code in iTapDone() is functional, if I copy the line and use it on SettingsStepDefs, it works.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to share an instance of `GenericStepDefs` between the steps. Since the variable `genericStepDefs` isn't set, you will get a NullPointerException.

You seem to be using Spring since you use the annotation `@Autowired`. Look into sharing state with Spring for Cucumber. It is done by setting up Spring for Cucumber-JVM. The dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

is needed.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your answer, I already have the dependency added. and could you be more specific with your solution ? how can i share an instance of GenericStepDefs between the steps? (if the dependency is not the only solution)